# How do I get a URL parameter?

Tags: ruby, url, parameters

I want to get the parameter of the URL:

```
http://server/index.rhtml?parameter=gonnadie
```

How do I get 'gonnadie'?

In PHP I would use `$_GET['parameter']`.

What do I use in Ruby?

Comment: I resolve this usin "servlet_request.query["parameter"]" + Webrick
thanks Dude

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolve this using `servlet_request.query["parameter"]` + `Webrick`
Thanks Dude

Answer (score 3):

Use the [URI::Parser](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3//libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/Parser.html) library as follows:

```
require 'uri'
str = 'http://server.index.rhtml?parameter=gonnadie'
parsed = Uri.parse(str)
parameters = parsed.query
paramvalue = parameters.split('=')
ourvalue = paramvalue[1]
```

Hope that helps...

Comment: how do I get the host in "URI.parse(here)"

Comment: not working this! how get the full URL? (http://server.index.rhtml?parameter=gonnadie)

Comment: No, I Want get the full URL, In PHP I would use $_SERVER{HTTP_HOST].$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI], What do I use in Ruby?

Comment: How is what I gave in my last comment not the full URL?

Comment: I would like to get the URL 'automatically'

Comment: s/Uri.parse(str)/URI.parse(str)

Answer (score 2):

`params[:parameter]`

Assuming you are talking about RAILS!

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'uri'
str = 'http://server/index.rhtml?parameter=gonnadie'
fulluri = Uri.parse(str).split('?')[0]
parameter = Uri.parse(str).split('=')[1]
```

Comment: I would like to get the URL 'automatically'